# Scheduled Tasks not working with Python Flask application when application is runs using gunicorn server

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, schedule

I have a small flask web application which runs a code after every 3600 seconds. Everything is working fine but the code is not executing the scheduled tasks after 3600 seconds. The scheduled code is as follows:

```
def run_every_hour():
    with app.app_context():        
        //Do some recurrent operations
def run_schedule():
    while 1:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1) 



  if __name__ == '__main__':   
        schedule.every(3600).seconds.do(run_every_hour)
        t = Thread(target=run_schedule)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        manager.run()
```

Everything works perfectly fine when the normal Flask server is being used. However, when I am using the gunicorn server the method `run_every_hour()` is not being called. Thank you for reading any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I am using Flask's server for this application so the above given code is working fine. Also other requests of the server have been entertained. However the problem with Flask server is it cannot handle multiple requests. So every now and then the application is crashed. So I have to restart the task from the deployment server in case server stops responding.
The right solution would be I should be using Gunicorn server,